# Does `bash` have an environment variable stack?

Tags: bash

I'm curious about whether `bash` has a stack for environment variables.

As an example of a usecase, it is apparently [good practice to `unset CDPATH` in a script](https://bosker.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/bash-scripters-beware-of-the-cdpath/). Of course, you'd want to restore the original value of `CDPATH` afterwards so that the script doesn't break the user's environment.

It'd be nice if we could do

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pushenv CDPATH
<script here>
popenv CDPATH
```

and call it day. Unfortunately, one has to mess around with these kinds of shenanigans:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
old_CDPATH="$CDPATH"
unset CDPATH
<script here>
CDPATH="$old_CDPATH"
unset old_CDPATH
```

Besides being messy, this poses a genuine issue. If the variable `old_CDPATH` may be in use already; if `$CDPATH` is used in the `<script here>` itself, it will break.

This is what stacks are used for, and is why the `pushd` and `popd` bash builtins exist. But do we have similar builtin functionality for arbitrary variables?

You may say "Just do things in a subshell, and don't export `old_CDPATH`" to which I say, **no, sometimes you have to run code (e.g. source scripts) in the same shell** (e.g. if the very purpose of those scripts is to modify environment variables.

So, how do we get stack-like behaviour? We could use this idiom:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a arr_old_CDPATH
function do_thing() {
  arr_old_CDPATH+="$CDPATH"
  unset CDPATH
  <script here>
  CDPATH="${arr_old_CDPATH[-1]}"
  unset arr_old_CDPATH[-1]
}
do_thing
```

We could even package it up into `pop` and `push` functions:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function push() { # $1 = stack (array) name, $2 = var name
  local -n arr=$1
  arr+=("${!2}")
  unset "$2"
}

function pop()  { # $1 = stack (array) name
  local -n arr=$1
  echo "${arr[-1]}"
  unset arr[-1]
}

push cdstack CDPATH
<script here>
CDPATH="$(pop CDPATH)"
```

We could also get more sophisticated, automatically creating a stack for each variable. Then we could just do "pop CDPATH":

```sh
declare _env_stack_name

env_stack_set_name() { # $1 = var name
  local stack_name=_stack_env_$1
  [ -v $stack_name ] || declare -ag $stack_name
  _env_stack_name=$stack_name
}
pushenv() { # $1 = var name
  env_stack_set_name $1
  local -n arr=$_env_stack_name
  arr+=("${!1}")
  unset "$1"
}
popenv() { # $1 = var name  
  env_stack_set_name $1
  local -n arr=$_env_stack_name
  local -n var=$1
  var=${arr[-1]}
  unset arr[-1]
}

pushenv CDPATH
<script here>
popenv CDPATH
```

This all seems quite excessive for basic stack functionality, which is required for complex scripts that need to run in a single shell.

Is there a better idiom for this or a more generic bash builtin than `pushd/popd` which can allow the pushing/popping of environment variables?

Comment: No, there's no built-in stack for environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `bash` have an environment variable stack?

No.

> As an example of a usecase, it is apparently good practice to `unset CDPATH` in a script. Of course, you'd want to restore the original value of `CDPATH` afterwards so that the script doesn't break the user's environment.

No, it is never necessary to restore the original value of any environment variable for the benefit of the parent process (including in the common case in which the parent is a shell).  No process can change another running process's environment, so a called (as opposed to `source`d) script's changes to its own environment have no effect on the environment of its parent process.

> **sometimes you have to run code (e.g. source scripts) in the same shell** (e.g. if the very purpose of those scripts is to modify environment variables.

Yes, but this is under the control of the author of the script doing the `sourcing`.  That's not to say that there is no use case for an environment variable stack, but in practice, it's not an especially important one.

Comment: I *am* the author of scripts doing sourcing. This is not an answer: "this use case is not important to me, so it's not important to you either".

Comment: @Myridium, the answer is at the very top: "No."  Bash does not have a built-in stack for variables.  Nor is there any standard idiom for it, because no matter how important it is to *you* (about which I make no assertion), it is not very important to most people.  I'm sorry if you don't like that answer, but it's the answer.

Comment: @Myridium, you might want to take a look at [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/), however.  This is not quite what you asked for, but it has some overlap, so perhaps it would serve your purposes.

Comment: "Is there a better idiom [...] which can allow the pushing/popping of environment variables?"

Comment: Thanks, environment modules may be useful.